# Query Comcast/Xfinity monthly data quota via .NET/C#

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnet-httpclient, quota, undocumented-behavior

The following code reports "error: unauthenticated".

How can I use .NET to authenticate against this Comcast/Xfinity API to query/fetch used and available data of an account with a monthly quota?

```
static async Task Main() {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://customer.xfinity.com/apis/services/internet/usage")) {
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var responseContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // {"error":"unauthenticated"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This code runs in either .NET Framework (tested 4.7.1) or .NET Core (tested 2.2). It authenticates with otherwise-defined `Username` and `Password` values and prints the data used and the data remaining in the month.

```
static async Task Main() {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        double totalUsage;
        double allowableUsage;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // this line can be removed in .NET Core
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://login.xfinity.com/login")) {
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"user", Username}
                , {"passwd", Password}
                , {"s", "oauth"}
                , {"continue", "https://oauth.xfinity.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=my-account-web&prompt=login&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcustomer.xfinity.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code"}
            };
            var content = string.Join("&", data.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value)}"));
            request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://customer.xfinity.com/apis/services/internet/usage")) {
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            var responseContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var parsedResponse = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
            var usageMonths = parsedResponse["usageMonths"];
            var currentMonthUsage = usageMonths.Last;
            totalUsage = currentMonthUsage.Value<double?>("totalUsage") ?? 0;
            allowableUsage = currentMonthUsage.Value<double?>("allowableUsage") ?? 0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Allowable: {allowableUsage}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total    : {totalUsage}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Depends on [nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.1](https://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.1)

Comment: I think you meant .NET Framework (4.7.1) and .NET Core (2.2) ;)

Comment: Correct! Thank you! I have fixed it.